# Android WebView OutOfMemory?

Tags: android, exception, error-handling, webview, out-of-memory

Sometimes by starting my activity which only contains a `WebView` I got this strange log from LogCat:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{de.cb.pwapp/de.cb.pwapp.Artikel}: 
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #9: Error inflating class android.webkit.WebView

at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2110)

at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2135)

at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:140)

at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1237)

at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)

at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)

at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4921)

at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)

at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)

at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1027)

at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:794)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #9: Error inflating class android.webkit.WebView
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:613)

at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)   
at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:660)

at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:685)

at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)

at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)

at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)

at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)

at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:313)

at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1924)

at de.cb.pwapp.Artikel.onCreate(Artikel.java:26)

at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5206)

at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1094)

at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2074)

... 11 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException

at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)

at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417)

at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:587)

... 24 more
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError

at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)

at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:625)

at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:478)

at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:781)

at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1963)

at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:601)

at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3449)

at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:432)

at android.widget.AbsoluteLayout.<init>(AbsoluteLayout.java:52)

at android.webkit.WebView.<init>(WebView.java:505)

at android.webkit.WebView.<init>(WebView.java:482)

at android.webkit.WebView.<init>(WebView.java:468)

at android.webkit.WebView.<init>(WebView.java:457)
```

Is it correct that my `WebView` runs out of memory ?

I load the `WebView` with a long string, representing an article, from my SQLite DB.

Any ideas how to fix this problem ?

Comment: Do you have a large bitmap that you're setting as a background somewhere?

Comment: YOur app is using too much memory.  What its allocating when it died may or may not be the problem.  YOu need to profile your app and see what large objects you have lieing around, see if objects aren't being cleaned, and figure out what's going on.  There's no quick fix to this without investigating.

Comment: Yep problem was that i had High Res pics as background ! 
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

High Res Pics as a Background was the Problem